# run a remote process via autossh in background

Tags: ssh, terminal, background-process, stdin

In Ubuntu I'm trying to run the `geany` editor on my local X display via the command:

```
 autossh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false -XCg me@otherDYNDNShost geany &
```

Trouble is, after the first disconnect & auto re-connect, I have to `fg` that process to make the (new) geany responsive again, in my local X windows session.  Which means that `disown` from the terminal caused it to get lost into a frozen sleeping state altogether, eventually.

How can I run this truly detached and independent of any terminal/tty?

Appending `<&-` to the command to cut off STDIN didn't seem to matter either.

Comment: Is it OK after the first disconnect, i.e. on subsequent reconnects will this problem happen again, or not? In the latter case detaching won't really help, maybe `tmux` or even `xpra` could help you a lot more here. Also the manual for autossh mentions `-f` did you try that?

Comment: `tmux`/`screen` may indeed be viable; `xpra` proved too resource intensive on my lean 1-2GB PCs in the past (behind the scenes X server).  In reality before having this problem I was trying to avoid using an `ssh` layer altogether, just sticking to classic `xhost +` over port 6000 (i.e. `DISPLAY=otherDYNDNShost:0 geany &`) but could still not figure out how to re-enable that network port in Ubuntu's X server, not even with `DisallowTCP=false` in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` as researched elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this with certificate authentication. It also provides dynamic proxy access to remote resources. It is my go-to way of doing remote IT Support with Linux and ssh. The ports I used are arbitrary...

```
autossh -M 18080 -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -D 8080 root@server -p 22
```

It will keep you connected to the same remote session if you use tmux called on the remote in the "~/.profiles" file like this. You can name sessions to be more specific if needed...

```
tmux attach
```

You will need to create a "~/.tmux.conf" file with this inside or tmux will nest sessions which is very messy...

```
new-session -n $HOST
```

I use it everyday with Debian based systems and with cygwin. For a deeper understanding try using Google for the above detail. You can configure tmux to start one or more programs as well. I have not tested this with auto starting X programs though.

Comment: Yes, I've been using `tmux` to get netbeans running in a detached but stable way (and minus all its buggy log noise on some terminal).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding *-f* to *autossh*. Description of *-f* from ssh man page:

> Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution. This
>   is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the
>   user wants it in the background. This implies -n. The recommended way
>   to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f
>   host xterm.

If it won't work, try using *daemon* (http://www.libslack.org/daemon/). In Debian and derivatives package is named *daemon*. Example:

```
daemon autossh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false -XCg me@otherDYNDNShost geany
```

Comment: Silly me, I tried `-f` right after posting and that worked, but felt bad about answering myself so fast. Thanks. However what's really annoying (and probably a different question) are its frequent disconnects & restarts, whilst another interactive ssh session seems way more tolerant of network hiccups and stays connected to one session.